# Get Last Email Content From Graph Message

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, office-js, microsoft-graph-sdks

I am wanting to get just the most recent message from an email using Graph. So I don't want the whole email chain, just the body or text content of the most recent email. Is this possible without HTML parsing?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the UniqueBody property https://learn.microsoft.com/en-au/graph/api/resources/message?view=graph-rest-1.0 that should contain what your after eg

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages?select=subject,receivedDateTime,conversationid,uniquebody
```